# Incompatability List <> using generic in java

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have the following code in JAVA :

```
List <? extends Number > l3=new List<Number>() ; // List not allowed ? why . and why arrayList is allowed here

Integer i=new Integer(5);

l3.add(i); // why we can not add i to l3 .
```

//-------------
another thing :

```
    List <?> variablex;
  variablex.add(new Integer(5) ); // error ? so why ?
```

I am wondered why I have these errors at compile time ?

Comment: Lets start from basic question: why do you want to use `List<? extends Number >` instead of `List<Number>` or maybe `List<Integer>`?

Comment: This question seems like duplicate of combination of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810691/instantiating-a-list-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495383/java-generics-wildcard-question-list-extends-a.

Answer (score 4):

You must have a concrete implementation of `List`, such as `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

```
List <? extends Number> l3 = new ArrayList<Number>() ;
```

Whenever you have a wildcard as a generic type parameter for a reference variable, it could stand for anything.  Here, with `? extends Number`, it can be any subclass of `Number` (or `Number`) itself.  It could be a `List<Double>`.  To maintain type safety, the compiler must disallow a call to `add` with an `Integer`, because `l3` could be a `List<Double>`, and you shouldn't be allowed to add an `Integer` to a `List` that may be of `Double`s.  With a `List<?>`, the wildcard could stand for anything.

```
List<?> l3 = new ArrayList<Number>();
// Later...
l3 = new LinkedList<MySpecialTypeYouDidntKnowAbout>();
// And then this doesn't work.
l3.add(new Integer(5));
```

Comment: "? extends Number" if it is not safe , then why it is allowed ?

Comment: @Michaagus *Adding* to it is not allowed. The expression itself is perfectly safe.

Comment: @Michaagus Generally, calling a method with a generic parameter such as `add`, on a generic class, results in type-unsafe code when the actual type of the variable is a wildcard.  There are other uses of `?` or `? extends SomeClass`, such as when you don't have to call such a method as `add`.

Comment: now 
  List <? extends Number > l3=new ArrayList <Integer>() ;  
  Integer i=new Integer(5); //   
  l3.add(i);// not allowed :( // it is Integer ? what should I use instead of Integer ,to allow it

Comment: @Michaagus You can call `add(anInteger)` on a `List<Integer>`, a `List<Number>`, and a `List<Object>`.

Comment: Why not with 
 List <? extends Number > l3

Comment: @Michaagus As I explained, the wildcard could stand for `Number` or any subtype, which may or may not be `Integer`.  To the compiler, it could be `List<BigDecimal>`.  For type safety reasons, the compiler doesn't let you add an `Integer` to something that could be a `List<BigDecimal>`.

Comment: "*Why not with `List <? extends Number >`*" Lets say you have `List<? extends Fruits>`. This list can hold `ArrayList<Apple>` or `ArrayList<Banana>`, but list doesn't know which type of list it holds so you could end up adding `Apple` to list of Bananas. To prevent such possibility `method(<? extends SomeType> argument)` is blocked by compiler (unless `argument` is `null`).

Comment: You can also call `add(anInteger)` on a `List<? super Integer>`, although I fail to imagine any reason why you ever would.

Answer (score 1):

`List` in an interface and you can't instantiate an interface.

`ArrayList` is an implementation of `List` interface and you can create object of class only.

Comment: so why not allowed in second ?

Comment: In second case you have not initialized it. you have just declared it.